# Is this considered valid c++11 or c++14? Or is gcc/clang getting it wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

While trying to solve [Is it possible to tell if a class has hidden a base function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746033/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-a-class-has-hidden-a-base-function-in-c), I generated this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#define ENABLE_IF(...) std::enable_if_t<(__VA_ARGS__), int> = 0

template<class T, class B, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<void(T::*)(), decltype(&T::x)>::value)>
auto has_x_f(T*) -> std::true_type;

template<class T, class B>
auto has_x_f(B*) -> std::false_type;

template<class T, class B>
using has_x = decltype(has_x_f<T, B>((T*)nullptr));

template<typename T>
struct A
{
  void x() {}

  static const bool x_hidden;

  template <typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value && x_hidden)>
  void y(R value)
  {
     std::cout << "x() is hidden" << std::endl;
  }

  template <typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value && !x_hidden)>
  void y(R value)
  {
     std::cout << "x() is not hidden" << std::endl;
  }

  //using t = std::integral_constant<bool, x_hidden>;
};

struct B : A<B>
{
    void x() {}
};

struct C : A<C>
{
};

template<typename T>
const bool A<T>::x_hidden = has_x<T, A<T>>::value;

int main()
{
  B b;
  C c;

  std::cout << "B: ";
  std::cout << b.x_hidden << std::endl;
  std::cout << "C: ";
  std::cout << c.x_hidden << std::endl;

  std::cout << "B: ";
  b.y(b);
  std::cout << "C: ";
  c.y(c);

  return 0;
}
```

Which outputs what I want:

```
B: 1
C: 0
B: x() is hidden
C: x() is not hidden
```

[clang](http://rextester.com/VFKIT77798) and [gcc](http://rextester.com/RBJD75979) both compile and execute this "correctly", but [vc++](http://rextester.com/IPREH96372) doesn't (though I am aware that there are problems with it working properly with expressions similar to `template <typename T> ... decltype(fn(std::declval<T>().mfn()))`).

So my question is, is this considered valid or will it break later on?  I'm also curious about the `x_hidden` being able to be used as a template parameter in the functions but not being able to use it in `using t = std::integral_constant<bool, x_hidden>`.  Is that just because the template's type isn't fully declared at this point?  If so, why did using it work for the function declarations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x_hidden` is false, there is no template arguements for which this template function

```
template <typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value && x_hidden)>
void y(R value) {
  std::cout << "x() is hidden" << std::endl;
}
```

can be instantiated, so your program is ill formed no diagnostic required.  This is a common hack, its illegality may be made clear or even legal at some point.

There may be a reason for using `has_x_f` instead of just directly initializing `is_hidden` with the `is_same` clause, but it isn't demonstrated in your code.

For any template specialization, there **must** be arguments which would make the instantiation valid.  If there are not, the program is ill-formed no diagnostic required.

I believe this clause is in the standard to permit compilers to do more advanced checks on templates, but not require them.

```
template <typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value && x_hidden)>
void y(R value)
{
   std::cout << "x() is hidden" << std::endl;
}
```

the compiler is free to notice `x_hidden` is `false`, and say "it doesn't matter what `is_same<T,R>` is", and deduce that *no template arguments could make this specialization valid*.  Then generate an error.

An easy hack is

```
template <class T2=T, class R,
  ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T2, R>::value && has_x<T2, A<T2>>::value)
>
void y(R value)
{
   std::cout << "x() is hidden" << std::endl;
}
```

where we sneak another template argument in that equals `T` usually.  Now, the compiler has to admit the possibility that `T2` passes the `has_x` test, and that the passed argument is `R`.  Users can bypass this by manually passing the "wrong" `T2`.

This may not solve everything.  The standard is a bit tricky to read here, but one reading states that if within the body of `y()` we go and assume that our `T` itself has `x()`, we still violate the rule of the possibility of a valid template instantiation.

[temp.res] 14.6/8 (root and 1)

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template [...] and the template is not instantiated, or

No valid specialization for

```
template <typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value && x_hidden)>
void y(R value)
{
  std::cout << "x() is hidden" << std::endl;
}
```

can be generated if `x_hidden` is false.  The exitence of another overload is immaterial.

If you fix it using the `T2` trick, the same rule holds *if the body assumes `T=T2`*.

Three are words in the standard that attempt to not cause the template to be instantiated in certain contexts, but I am unsure if that makes the above code well formed or not.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143355/discussion-on-answer-by-yakk-is-this-considered-valid-c11-or-c14-or-is-gcc).

Comment: So in essence, you can just remove everything starting from "Still this doesn't ..". If you are still unsure about it, I recommend that you ask a new question or post to std-discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I tried compiling your code with the Intel C++ compiler(icpc (ICC) 17.0.2 20170213), and it would not compile with the following message:

```
main.cpp(30): error: expression must have a constant value
    template <typename R, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<T, R>::value && !x_hidden)>
                          ^

/home/com/gcc/6.2.0/bin/../include/c++/6.2.0/type_traits(2512): error: class "std::enable_if<<error-constant>, int>" has no member "type"
      using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
                                                          ^
          detected during instantiation of type "std::enable_if_t<<error-constant>, int>" at line 30 of "main.cpp"

main.cpp(62): error: more than one instance of overloaded function "B::y" matches the argument list:
            function template "void A<T>::y(R) [with T=B]"
            function template "void A<T>::y(R) [with T=B]"
            argument types are: (B)
            object type is: B
    b.y(b);
```

I was however able to compile the following with both the Intel compiler and GCC.

```
#include <iostream>

#define ENABLE_IF(...) std::enable_if_t<(__VA_ARGS__), int> = 0

template<class T, class B, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<void(T::*)(), decltype(&T::x)>::value)>
auto has_x_f(T*) -> std::true_type;

template<class T, class B>
auto has_x_f(B*) -> std::false_type;

template<class T, class B>
using has_x = decltype(has_x_f<T, B>((T*)nullptr));

template<class T>
class A
{
   public:
      T& self() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }

      void x() { }

      template
         <  class TT = T
         ,  typename std::enable_if<has_x<TT, A<TT> >::value, int>::type = 0
         >
      void y()
      {
         std::cout << " have x hidden " << std::endl;
         // if you are so inclined, you can call x() in a "safe" way
         this->self().x(); // Calls x() from class "Derived" (Here class B)
      }

      template
         <  class TT = T
         ,  typename std::enable_if<!has_x<TT, A<TT> >::value, int>::type = 0
         >
      void y()
      {
         std::cout << " does not have x hidden " << std::endl;
         // if you are so inclined, you can call x() in a "safe" way
         this->self().x(); // Calls x() from class "Base" (Here class A)
      }
}; 

class B : public A<B>
{
   public:
      void x() { }
}; 

class C : public A<C>
{
};


int main()
{
   B b;
   C c;

   b.y();
   c.y();

   return 0;
}
```

I am not aware whether or not this is incorrect according to the standard however, but as I see it you do not run into the problem mentioned in one of the other answers, that you have a template that cannot be instantiated.

---

EDIT: I was able to get to compile on MSVC 2017 by some "old-times" template metaprogramming tricks, and using classes instead of functions.
If I use this implementation of `has_x` instead it compiles:

```
template<class T, bool>
struct has_x_impl;

template<class T>
struct has_x_impl<T, true>: std::true_type
{
};

template<class T>
struct has_x_impl<T, false>: std::false_type
{
};

template<class T>
using has_x = has_x_impl<T, std::is_same<void(T::*)(), decltype(&T::x)>::value>;
```

Full code on Wandbox [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZbPN7rJRvEgGkX61).

Comment: This looks like a good reasolution.  Note, however, that the body of `y` *must* be valid if someone passed in at least one "accepable" `TT` manually.  If no `TT` makes the body valid (say, the `y` where `TT` `has_x`accessing a `T`'s `.x()` method), the program remains ill-formed no diagnostic required.

Comment: @Yakk So if I understand you correctly: As long as no one calls y() with an explicit template argument (like e.g. b.y<D>() ) we are home free?

Comment: Note quite: if the body of `y()` *presumes* that `TT=T`, and would not compile if it was not true, it still violates the letter of the "valid template instantiation" requirement.  Ie, the one where `has_x<TT, A<TT>>` is true cannot *assume* it is true for `T` as well as `TT`.  This is subtle but tricky.

Comment: @Yakk I agree, but the function is implicitly only made to work for the "curiosly derived" class, and as such should never be called with an explicit template argument. Under that restriction do we agree that it is "legal" in all cases? The optimal thing would probably be to remove the depence of A<TT> from has_x also.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of a code clean-up (got rid of the out-of-line `x_hidden` declaration) and ended up with the following. I also fixed it slightly based on @Yakk's answer above, to avoid [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8) invalidating it.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#define ENABLE_IF(...) std::enable_if_t<(__VA_ARGS__), int> = 0

template<class T, class Base, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<void(T::*)(), decltype(&T::x)>::value)>
auto has_x_f() -> std::true_type;

template<class T, class Base, ENABLE_IF(std::is_same<void(Base::*)(), decltype(&T::x)>::value)>
auto has_x_f() -> std::false_type;

template<class T, class Base>
using has_x = decltype(has_x_f<T, Base>());

template<typename T>
struct A
{
  void x() {}

  static bool constexpr x_hidden() {
      return has_x<T, A<T>>::value;
  }

  void y()
  {
      assert(x_hidden() == y_<T>(nullptr) );
  }

  void y2()
  {
      if constexpr(x_hidden()) {
          typename T::BType i = 1;
          (void)i;
      } else {
          typename T::CType i = 1;
          (void)i;
      }
  }


private:
  template <typename R, typename T2=T, ENABLE_IF(A<T2>::x_hidden())>
  static bool y_(R*)
  {
     std::cout << "x() is hidden" << std::endl;
     return true;
  }

  template <typename R, typename T2=T, ENABLE_IF(!A<R>::x_hidden())>
  static bool y_(T*)
  {
     std::cout << "x() is not hidden" << std::endl;
     return false;
  }
};

struct B : A<B>
{
    void x() {}
    using BType = int;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&B::x), void(B::*)()>::value, "B::x is a member of B");

struct C : A<C>
{
    using CType = int;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&C::x), void(A<C>::*)()>::value, "C::x is a member of A<C>");

int main()
{
  B b;
  C c;

  std::cout << "B: ";
  std::cout << B::x_hidden() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "C: ";
  std::cout << C::x_hidden() << std::endl;

  std::cout << "B: ";
  b.y();
  b.y2();
  std::cout << "C: ";
  c.y();
  c.y2();

  return 0;
}
```

[Live demo on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UJ3tKe6P7ODRfxLB) -- gcc and clang are both happy with it.

[MSVC 2017](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) complained

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
>   for both uses of `A<T2>::x_hidden()`, when instantiating `A<B>` for `B` to inherit from.

[MSVC 2015](http://rextester.com/IMXO52025) gave the same complaint, and then suffered an Internal Compiler Error. ^_^

So I think this is valid, but exercises MSVC's `constexpr` or template instantiation machinery in unpleasant ways.

Per the example in [[expr.unary.op]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3), the type of `&B::x` is `void (B::*)()`, and the type of `&C::x` is `void (A<C>::*)()`. So the first `has_x_f()` will be present when `T` is `B`, and the second `has_x_f()` will be present when `T` is `C` and `Base` is `A<C>`.

Per [[temp.inst]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-2), instantiating the class instantiates declarations but not definitions of the members. Per [[temp.inst]/3 and 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-3), member function definitions (including template functions) are not instantiated until required.

Our declarations here are *currently* different, as the use of `R` and `T2` mean the compiler cannot determine the truth or falsehood of either size of the `&&`.

The use of the different parameter types helps MSVC, which would otherwise see them as redefinitions of the same template member template function. My reading of [[temp.inst]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-2) says this is not needed, as they're only redefintions when we instantiate them, and they cannot be instantiated at the same time. Because we use `A<T2>::x_hidden()` and `!A<R>::x_hidden()`, the compiler cannot know that they are mutually exclusive at this time. I don't think it's necessary to do that to avoid [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8), simply using `A<R>::x_hidden()` seems safe-enough to me. This was also to ensure that in the two templates, `R` as actually used.

From there on, it's pretty easy. `y()` shows we have the right values coming from both paths.

Depend on your use-case, you could use `if constexpr` with `x_hidden()` to avoid all the template magic in `y_()`, per `y2()` above.

This avoids the issue with [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8) described in @Yakk's answer, as the problematic clause [[temp.res]/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1) is that the template is ill-formed if

> no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, [...]

So as long as you instantiate `A<T>::y2()` for *some* `T`, then you're not subject to this clause.

The `y2()` approach has the advantage of working with MSVC2017, as long as you pass in the "/std:c++latest" compiler flag.